# Advanced Control of Topology in Solidworks

Tags: blender, cad, solidworks

Once upon a time, I tried to model accurate LEGO blocks on blender, but I made a mistake with the dimensions.  Then I found out that I could model LEGOs a thousand times faster using Solidworks.  Since I wanted to use the LEGO blocks for animations, I wanted to model the LEGOs in Solidworks and then export them to a file that I could use in blender.  Everything worked out as planned except the topology.  What I wanted was an octagon top where the corners of the octagon alternate between going toward the corners of the square-shaped LEGO brick and cutting it down the middle as shown in this picture (I modeled this with Blender):

[image: Good topology modeled with blender]

However, when I exported the model from Solidworks, I got this:

[image: Bad topology modeled with Solidworks]

I tried changing the resolution of the export down, but it didn't help as much as I wanted it to.  I could try chaning the circle on top to an octagon in Solidworks, but I would still have the problem that the corners of the octagon will all go toward the corners of the square rather than down the middle.

Is there a way to define the topology of a Solidworks part for exporting it either in Solidworks or through a third-party program that does that?

Answer (score 1):

During geometry export from SolidWorks, you need to change the chordal error (deviation) and max angle (between triangles normals) to obtain the result in your first picture.

From SolidWorks documentation:

- http://help.solidworks.com/2010/english/solidworks/sldworks/legacyhelp/sldworks/impexp/hidd_stl.htm

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using different formats. Check what formats Blender can import and what solidworks can export to match.

Also this may not be the best place for a question like that. I'd suggest to post it on [solidworks forum](https://forum.solidworks.com/). Good luck.

Comment: I've tried using different file formats, but I came up with the same result.  I wondered if this would be a bit off topic for here, so I'll try asking it on the solidworks forum.  Thanks.